# Sollte in diesem Satz nicht der Konjunktiv verwendet werden?

Tags: word-choice, subjunctive, lyrics

Im [*letzten Spielmann*](http://www.magistrix.de/lyrics/Saltatio%20Mortis/Der-Letzte-Spielmann-1131464.html) von Saltatio Mortis lautet der Refrain:

> So frag ich mich
>   Nicht erst seit heute,
>   Wie es denn wohl **ist,**
>   Wenn ich der Gott
>   Und du auf Erden
>   Der letzte Spielmann **bist.**

Immer, wenn ich mitsingen möchte, setze ich automatisch statt *ist* und *bist* *wär* und *wärst* ein. Für mich klingt es irgendwie komisch, die Sätze im Indikativ statt im Konjunktiv (II) zu formulieren. Allerdings reimt sich nur der Indikativ.

Gibt es außer reimtaktischen noch andere Gründe, warum an dieser Stelle statt des Konjunktivs der Indikativ stehen soll?

Comment: Geht ja ziemlich durcheinander, wenn ich mir da den gesamten Text so anschaue … _Dichterische Freiheit_, würde ich sagen.

Comment: Ein Random-Downvote über ein Jahr nach Fragestellung ohne Kommentar?

Comment: Zusatzfrage: Wenn ich den (klar aus reimtaktischen Gründen so formulierten) Vers in den grammatisch sauberen und stilistisch guten Konjunktiv umformuliere, stoße ich darauf, dass sowohl "Wie es denn wohl wäre" als als auch "Wie es denn wohl sei" möglich scheinen, letzteres eher altertümlich im Ausdruck aber gleichwohl korrekt. Liege ich damit richtig? Oder würde ein Grammaticus Argumente finden, dass eine der Varianten falsch sei?

Comment: Die Alternativen haben jedenfalls den Nachteil, dass sie sich nicht reimen (wär/sei - wärst), im Gegensatz zu ist - bist.

Comment: @christiangeiselmann Mach eine richtige Frage daraus :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretisch wäre es denkbar, dass er das Präsens als Futur verwendet und damit impliziert, dieses Szenario könne wahr werden. Ich glaube jedoch, dass er sich wenig um die Grammatik schert. Siehe hier:

> du gäbst ein Dreck auf die Gebote  und hättest Spaß dabei!

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem deutschen Stackexchange! +1 für die textkonsistente Interpretation ;) (Und weil die Antwort mir gut und richtig erscheint).

Answer (score 2):

In gesprochener Alltagssprache weden Konjunktivregeln bei indirekter Rede kaum beachtet, ja, indirekte Rede wird regelrecht umgangen.

Comment: Nur dass ich auch in direkter Rede mich fragen würde »Wie wär es denn, wenn ich der Gott und du auf Erden der letzte Spielmann wärst.« Richtige Beobachtung aber für die Frage meines Erachtens wenig relevant …

Comment: Schon richtig. Aber die Leute sagen es auch anders. Ich würde sagen, nicht alle Leute sind in Ìrrealis-Formen geschult.